# Como simular a função title do Python [string.title()] no Java?

Tags: java, python

No python, a string tem uma função chamada title, que faz que um texto fique que nem um título. Tem uma função assim no Java? Se não, como fazê-la?

Exemplo:
"oi, meu nome é goku".title() -> "Oi, Meu Nome É Goku"

Eu preciso dessa função pois estou trabalhando com nomes de pessoas, e o nome da pessoa tem que ficar assim.

Outro Exemplo:
freterotilda astrobalda -> Freterotilda Astrobalda

Comment: Cuidado com nomes como Freterotilda da Silva: o "da" geralmente tem de ficar em minúsculas.

Answer (score 2):

A biblioteca [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) conta com a função `capitalize` na classe [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html).

```
String title = WordUtils.capitalize("oi, meu nome é goku");
```

Se você precisa normalizar um título além da primeira letra existe também a função `capitalizeFully`.

```
String title = WordUtils.capitalizeFully("oi, meu nOME é gOKU");
```

---

**Fonte:** [SOen - Capitalize First Char of Each Word in a String Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java)

Comment: Existe algum método que já venha no Java? Ou, você sabe fazer essa função?

Comment: Que eu saiba não existe um método na própria API, criar o método é bem mole: basicamente fazer um `split` na `String` e capitalizar a primeira letra de cada palavra resultante, então concatená-las novamente. Porém com uma biblioteca você ganha robustez (nunca reinvente a roda). Se você quer ver como a Apache implementou esse método de uma olhada [no código fonte](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html) da classe.